# how to validate e-mail using class library in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project in windows form, which contains a email validation function.
can you suggest any idea how to do email validation fun as dll by adding reference to my windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create class library 
Go to File Menu -> New -> Project.
Select Project Type “Visual Basic” and Template “Class Library”.
Give project name as “EmailValidation” and click OK.

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Function email(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
        Dim str1 As String
        str1 = str
        If InStr(str1, "@") > 0 Then
            If InStr(str1, ".") > 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Select Build -> Build Solution or press ctrl+shift+B. to create dll file